# Is there a way to make python pickle ignore "it's not the same object " errors

Tags: python, datetime, mocking, pickle

Is there a way to make python pickle ignore  "it's not the same object " errors?

I'm writing a test using Mock to have fine grain control over the results that datetime.utcnow() produces. The code I'm using is time sensitive so mock's patch  makes it easy to test.

The same tests need to pickle objects and send the results to a remote server. For the purpose of the test if a standard datetime was pickled and received by the remote server everything would be fine.

Unfortunately the pickle module is barfing with the following error:

> Can't pickle <type 'datetime.datetime'>: it's not the same object as
>   datetime.datetime

Here is a minimal example to reproduce the error.

```
from mock import patch
from datetime import datetime
import pickle

class MockDatetime(datetime):
  frozendt = datetime(2011,05,31)

  @classmethod
  def advance(cls, **kw):
    cls.frozendt = cls.frozendt + timedelta(**kw)

  @classmethod
  def utcnow(cls):
    return cls.frozendt

@patch('datetime.datetime', MockDatetime)
def test():
  pickle.dumps(datetime.utcnow())

if __name__ == '__main__':
  test()
```

Is there some  combo of  `__reduce__` and `__getstate__` methods that might trick the pickle machinery into thinking MockDatetime is a datetime when I pickle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the [where to patch](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch) section in the documentation I see this advice:

> The basic principle is that you patch where an object is *used*, which is not necessarily the same place as where it is defined.

Following this recommendation, I've tried to replace:

```
@patch('datetime.datetime', MockDatetime)
```

with:

```
@patch('__main__.datetime', MockDatetime)
```

and I didn't get any error from `pickle`. Also, I added a `print` statement to make sure that `datetime` was really being patched and I got the expected value.

Answer (score 5):

In case someone wants a generic solution to pickle mocks:

```
m = mock.MagicMock()
m.__reduce__ = lambda self: (mock.MagicMock, ())
```

Note that this doesn't seem to save internal content of the used mock (e.g calls).

Comment: Minus one as this clearly does not save any state of the object.