# Pickling dynamically created types

Tags: python, pickle

I've been trying to get some dynamically created types (i.e. ones created by calling 3-arg `type()`) to pickle and unpickle nicely. I've been using [this module switching trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7668273/168175) to hide the details from users of the module and give clean semantics.

I've learned several things already:

1. The type must be findable with `getattr` on the module itself
2. The type must be consistent with what `getattr` finds, that is to say if we call `pickle.dumps(o)` then it must be true that `type(o) == getattr(module, 'name of type')`

Where I'm stuck though is that there still seems to be something odd going on - it seems to be calling `__getstate__` on something unexpected.

Here's the simplest setup I've got that reproduces the issue, testing with Python 3.5, but I'd like to target back to 3.3 if possible:

```
# module.py
import sys
import functools

def dump(self):
    return b'Some data' # Dummy for testing

def undump(self, data):
    print('Undump: %r' % data) # Do nothing for testing

# Cheaty demo way to make this consistent
@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def make_type(name):
    return type(name, (), {
        '__getstate__': dump,
        '__setstate__': undump,
    })

class Magic(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print('Getting thing: %s (from: %s)' % (name, self.path))
        # for simple testing all calls to make_type must end in last x.y.z.last
        if name != 'last':
            if self.path:
                return Magic(self.path + '.' + name)
            else:
                return Magic(name)
        return make_type(self.path + '.' + name)

# Make the switch
sys.modules[__name__] = Magic('')
```

And then a quick way to exercise that:

```
import module
import pickle

f=module.foo.bar.woof.last()
print(f.__getstate__()) # See, *this* works
print('Pickle starts here')
print(pickle.dumps(f))
```

Which then gives:

```
Getting thing: foo (from: )
Getting thing: bar (from: foo)
Getting thing: woof (from: foo.bar)
Getting thing: last (from: foo.bar.woof)
b'Some data'
Pickle starts here
Getting thing: __spec__ (from: )
Getting thing: _initializing (from: __spec__)
Getting thing: foo (from: )
Getting thing: bar (from: foo)
Getting thing: woof (from: foo.bar)
Getting thing: last (from: foo.bar.woof)
Getting thing: __getstate__ (from: foo.bar.woof)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(pickle.dumps(f))
TypeError: 'Magic' object is not callable
```

I wasn't expecting to see anything looking up `__getstate__` on `module.foo.bar.woof`, but even if we force that lookup to fail by adding:

```
if name == '__getstate__': raise AttributeError()
```

into our `__getattr__` it still fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(pickle.dumps(f))
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'module.Magic'>: it's not the same object as module.Magic
```

What gives? Am I missing something with `__spec__`? The [docs for `__spec__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__spec__) pretty much just stress setting it appropriately, but don't seem to actually explain much.

More importantly the bigger question is how am I supposed to go about making types I programatically generated via a pseudo module's `__getattr__` implementation pickle properly?

(And obviously once I've managed to get `pickle.dumps` to produce something I expect `pickle.loads` to call `undump` with the same thing)

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use the module switching trick? I simplified your example a bit and it works fine with `module.Magic('').foo.bar.woof.last()`. The module switch causes the `it's not the same object` error. I'm still working out the details of what causes all these problems though.

Answer (score 1):

To pickle `f`, `pickle` needs to pickle `f`'s class, `module.foo.bar.woof.last`.

The docs don't claim support for pickling arbitrary classes. [They claim the following](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled):

> The following types can be pickled:
>
> - ...
> - classes that are defined at the top level of a module

`module.foo.bar.woof.last` isn't defined at the top level of a module, even a pretend module like `module`. In this not-officially-supported case, the pickle logic ends up trying to pickle `module.foo.bar.woof`, either [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3410c01d83d70ceef48b735c247aebd2d5bd3411/Lib/pickle.py#L948-L949):

```
    elif parent is not module:
        self.save_reduce(getattr, (parent, lastname))
```

or [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2ebc5ce42a8a9e047e790aefbf9a94811569b2b6/Modules/_pickle.c#L3279)

```
    else if (parent != module) {
        PickleState *st = _Pickle_GetGlobalState();
        PyObject *reduce_value = Py_BuildValue("(O(OO))",
                                    st->getattr, parent, lastname);
        status = save_reduce(self, reduce_value, NULL);
```

`module.foo.bar.woof` can't be pickled for multiple reasons. It returns a non-callable `Magic` instance for all unsupported method lookups, like `__getstate__`, which is where your first error comes from. The module-switching thing prevents finding the `Magic` class to pickle it, which is where your second error comes from. There are probably more incompatibilities.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems, and is already proven that making the class `callable` is just a drifting out another wrong direction, thankfully to [this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8512365/4571206), I could find a getaround to make the class reiterable by its TYPE. following the context of the error `<class 'module.Magic'>: it's not the same object as module.Magic` the pickler doesn't iterate through the same call that renders a different type from the other one, this is a major common problem with pickling self instanciating classes, for this instance, an object by its class, there for the solution is patching the class with its type `@mock.patch('module.Magic', type(module.Magic))` this is a short answer for a something.

**Main.py**

```
import module
import pickle
import mock


f=module1.foo.bar.woof.last
print(f().__getstate__()) # See, *this* works
print('Pickle starts here')
@mock.patch('module1.Magic', type(module1.Magic))
def pickleit():
    return pickle.dumps(f())
print(pickleit())
```

**Magic class**

```
class Magic(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.path = value

    __class__: lambda x:x

    def __getstate__(self):
        print ("Shoot me! i'm at " +  self.path )
        return dump(self)

   def __setstate__(self,value):
        print ('something will never occur')
        return undump(self,value)

    def __spec__(self):
        print ("Wrong side of the planet ")

    def _initializing(self):
        print ("Even farther lost ")

     def __getattr__(self, name):
        print('Getting thing: %s (from: %s)' % (name, self.path))
        # for simple testing all calls to make_type must end in last x.y.z.last
        if name != 'last':
            if self.path:
                return Magic(self.path + '.' + name)
            else:
                return Magic(name)
        print('terminal stage' )
        return make_type(self.path + '.' + name)
```

Even assuming this is not more of striking the ball by the edge of the bat, I could see the content dumped into my console.