# Testing a function with a @cache.memoize gives PicklingError

Tags: flask, caching, mocking, pytest

I have some tests for functions that use cache, for example:

Function:

```
@retry(stop=stop_after_attempt(3))
@cache.cached(timeout=60, key_prefix='resouce_group_list')
def get_azure_resource_groups():

    data = []
    resource_client = get_azure_resource_client()
    for item in resource_client.resource_groups.list():
        data.append(item)
    return data
```

Test:

```
@patch("dev_maintenance.machines.get_azure_resource_client")
def test_get_azure_list_rg(get_azure_resource_client):

    cache.clear()
    data = []
    with app.app_context():
        ret = get_azure_resource_groups()
        get_azure_resource_client.assert_called_once()
        expected = get_azure_resource_client.return_value.resource_groups.list.return_value
        assert len(get_azure_resource_client.return_value.method_calls) == 1
        for item in expected:
            data.append(item)
        assert ret == data
        cache.clear()
```

The above test works fine, it passes, no errors and the test is using cache.

But i got other tests, and the decorator here does not matter, it will give the same error if i change the decorator to `@cache.cache`:

Function:

```
@retry(stop=stop_after_attempt(3))
@cache.memoize(60)
def get_azure_machine_info(rg_name, machine_name, expand="instanceView"):

    try:
        compute_client = get_azure_compute_client()
        return compute_client.virtual_machines.get(rg_name, machine_name, expand=expand)
    except CloudError:
        return None
```

Test:

```
@patch("dev_maintenance.machines.get_azure_compute_client")
def test_get_azure_machine_info (get_azure_compute_client):

    cache.delete_memoized(get_azure_machine_info)
    with app.app_context():
        ret = get_azure_machine_info("rg1", "m1")
        print(ret)
        get_azure_compute_client.assert_called_once()
        assert len(get_azure_compute_client.return_value.method_calls) == 1
        assert (
            ret == get_azure_compute_client.return_value.virtual_machines.get.return_value
            )

        get_azure_compute_client.return_value.virtual_machines.get.assert_called_once_with(
            "rg1", "m1", expand="instanceView"
            )
        cache.delete_memoized(get_azure_machine_info)
```

Now here the test fails with the error on this line `ret = get_azure_machine_info("rg1", "m1")`:

```
value = None, from_value = PicklingError("Can't pickle <class 'unittest.mock.MagicMock'>: it's not the same object as unittest.mock.MagicMock")

>   ???
E   tenacity.RetryError: RetryError[<Future at 0x105c7c3d0 state=finished raised PicklingError>]

<string>:3: RetryError
```

I tried to mock the cache passing a patch decorator like:

```
@patch("dev_maintenance.machines.cache") or @patch("dev_maintenance.cache")
```

I tried to set the CACHE_TYPE to null in the test case, instantiating the cache object and passing the config:

```
cache = Cache()
cache.init_app(app, config={"CACHE_TYPE": "redis"})
```

but no success so far, any help?

Comment: which line is throwing the error?

Comment: ret = get_azure_machine_info("rg1", "m1")

Answer (score 0):

This is a reference to an old answer, but I think that generally MagicMock objects aren't meant to be pickled: https://github.com/thadeusb/flask-cache/issues/52

That error message is different though, and this is more similar to what you are seeing:
[Is there a way to make python pickle ignore "it's not the same object " errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381049/is-there-a-way-to-make-python-pickle-ignore-its-not-the-same-object-errors)

**Maybe** you could replace the domain prefix to the class like the answer above, but I am not sure it will overcome the other difficulties of pickling a `MagicMock` class:

```
`@patch("__main__.get_azure_compute_client")`
```

Comment: I've also tried that because i saw that post, but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I'am writing the answer here for people that need to test functions that are cached with flask-caching and have the same error then me.

What i needed was to create an Object inside the test and make the `mock_value` = `Object` like this:

First i create a simple class:

```
class MachineInfo(object):
    pass
```

Then in my test:

```
@patch("dev_maintenance.machines.get_azure_compute_client")
def test_get_azure_machine_info (get_azure_compute_client):

    cache.clear()
    expected_res = MachineInfo()
    expected_res.id = "id"
    expected_res.name = "machine1"
    expected_res.location = "location"
    expected_res.hardware_profile = "hardware"
    expected_res.storage_profile = "storage"
    expected_res.network_profile = "network_profile"
    get_azure_compute_client.return_value.virtual_machines.get.return_value = expected_res
    res = get_azure_machine_info("rg1", "m1")
    assert res == expected_res
    cache.clear()
```

Then i could assert `function_call() == Object` or `function_call() == mock.return_value`

This simulates what the actual azure returns, an object, so i just make the mock return the object that i created so i can simulate the function itself.